# Minus is not printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I write

```
pyautogui.typewrite(to_type)
```

to script for automatization keyboad and mouse. to_type = -0.2 and it write only 0.2. I have english keyboard. It writes without minus for

```
pyautogui.typewrite(-0.2)
```

as well. Do you have an idea where is the problem? Thank you

Code

```
import pyautogui 
import time 
for i in range(1, 3): 
    pyautogui.click(509, 679) # move to field 
    pyautogui.typewrite(['backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace']) 
    value = -0.5 + (i - 1) * 0.3 # computation numbers that will be write in field 
    to_type = "%f" % value 
    print(to_type) 
    #pyautogui.press('-')
    pyautogui.typewrite(to_type) # writing previous number 
    time.sleep(2) 
    pyautogui.typewrite(['enter']) # enter the input of number 
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.5
    pyautogui.click(169, 681) # plot
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.5
    pyautogui.click(330, 685) # save 
    pyautogui.click(448, 174) # file name 
    to_type = "data{}".format(i) 
    print(to_type) 
    pyautogui.typewrite(to_type) # writing name of file 
    pyautogui.click(978, 664) # save file
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.5
```

Comment: The docs say `typewrite` takes a string, not a float.

Comment: In fact, looking at the pyautogui code, that should have outright thrown a TypeError. Post something that *runs* and *reproduces the problem* when run. We can't run this.

Comment: I added a code to mz question

Comment: What are you having `pyautogui` type this into? Does the thing you're auto-typing into actually allow a negative sign?

Comment: I tried to transform it to string too

Comment: I don't know. It is not probably allowed. How to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194403/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-user2357112).

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: What can be the problem by me? In terminal it is right but in required program not

Comment: Could you look at that program via TeamViewer please?

Answer (score 1):

`typewrite` [takes a string](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-typewrite-function), but you've passed a float. Try this:

```
pyautogui.typewrite("-0.2")
```

Comment: `pyautogui.press('-')
    pyautogui.typewrite(to_type)` this doesn~t work as well

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell me how to help you. What happens when that line executes?

Comment: It control a program, It is necessary to write a number in it. Some of numbers should be negative, but all of them are positive